# Flutter, nested futurebuilder? How to refresh only one widget within futurebuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to build dashboard for sports app, which consists of calendar that holds events, some other info and list of players within team. Upon opening dashboard function getDashboard(teamid) gets called which loads all of the data including calendar and event data.
My calendar has button to switch months, data about next months isn't loaded just because it doesn't make sense to load years worth of data when most of the times only current months data is used.

Currently all of the code is wrapped in futurebuilder.

it looks something like this

```
        FutureBuilder<TeamDashboardDto?>(
              future: _teamDashboardDto,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                {
                      return SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [ 
    SomeWidgetsThatcontainInformation(),
Calendar( events: snapshot.data.eventList),
PlayerList(data: snapshotData),
    ], ), ), }, )
```

Although UI ir horrendous i hope you get the idea.
[image]

I dont want to reload all of the data, i just want to refresh Calendar data and while its being loaded I wish to replace calendar with loading icon. Is this possible? Or maybe I should just reload all dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't completely understand the question, I would recommend making future requests on initstate then on the click of a button make a new future request and use setstate to update your UI. This in turn gives you flexibility.